# Tracing PHP-Exception Logs with New Relic

Tags: php, newrelic

**The Issue**:
We want to trace log-messages with New Relic. The log text, is the product of Exceptions, in a PHP-Application. Until now, we wrote Exception messages into the database, and are facing serious memory space problems.

**Actual State**:
PHP Agent is installed and available (theoretically).

**The Question**:
Which Method to call using the New Relic PHP-API?! What are the steps to receive the goal to write error messages manually?

Answer (score 3):

I think the API-call I was looking for was '**newrelic_notice_error (message, exception)**'.

Comment: Adding Reference to docs: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/php-agent/php-agent-api/newrelic_notice_error/